# Modifying the first print of if in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a for loop that is carrying data. I have an if checking for a specific type and based on that, elements will be created. Because I am using bootstrap, the first print need to have an "active" class in it. Any ideas on how I can grab that first print to modify it? Please and thanks

```
                 for(var i in data.response.result){
                    var disContent = data.response.result[i];
                    var contentType = disContent.type;

                    if(contentType == "article"){
                      var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
                      $(itemDiv).addClass("carousel-item");

                      var itemImg = document.createElement("img");
                      var img = disContent.listImage.thumbnail;
                      $(itemImg).addClass("d-block w-100");
                      itemImg.src = img;

                      //if(first print){
                      // $(itemDiv).addClass("active");
                      //}

                      $(itemDiv).append(itemImg);
                      $("#inner").append(itemDiv);
                    }

                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Boolean to check if an item is the first or not:

```js
var first = true;
for (var i in data.response.result) {
    var disContent = data.response.result[i];
    var contentType = disContent.type;

    if (contentType == "article") {
        var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        $(itemDiv).addClass("carousel-item");
        first && ($(itemDiv.addClass("active")), first = false);

        var itemImg = document.createElement("img");
        var img = disContent.listImage.thumbnail;
        $(itemImg).addClass("d-block w-100");
        itemImg.src = img;

        //if(first print){
        // $(itemDiv).addClass("active");
        //}

        $(itemDiv).append(itemImg);
        $("#inner").append(itemDiv);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works smooth

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

1. use a flag (existing answer)
2. check on each loop, just before append (slow)

   `if ($("#inner>div").length === 0) $(itemDiv).addClass("active");`
3. add it after the for loop

   `$("#inner>div.carousel-item:first()").addClass("active");`